# Identity Bounded Context for a small eCommerce System

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have to develop an eCommerce website following DDD.
I just completed Ardalis and Julie DDD pluralsight course and need to come up with bounded-context for this project.
**Can you please assist if I properly identify bounded contexts for this project?**

**The requirement is as follow :**

The system has 3 types of users : Admin, Manager, and Customer

The system needs to record products, then will display them on online listing,
customer users needs to be able to log invoice which must contain : products added to the invoice + the total

Manager user must be able to edit all invoice.

System must have report on all product sold, in-stock, total products

System must have notification sent to managers only about products that need to be replenished.

**I'm thinking of creating 3 bounded context as follow :**

1. Product Management (record, list, invoicing)
   *For me, Invoice should be a value-object as it doesn't make sense alone, it has always to be associated with customer user.*
2. Report Management
3. User Management (Admin, Manager, Customer)

Regarding notification, I'm gonna just use Domain Event, no need for a specific bounded-context for it.

**Can you please help me to properly identify bounded contexts for this project?**

Comment: Just to challenge your thinking on Invoice a little: when someone goes to pay an invoice, how do you know which one? Usually, an invoice has a number/id to be able to pay a _specific_ invoice. You almost certainly want an invoice to be an entity, not a value object.

Comment: @RobH Thanks. We'll change it to Entity.

Comment: @RobH If Invoice is an Entity, what are going to be value objects then ?

Comment: @RobH According to Eric Evans's book, he said **try to use Value object instead of entities wherever possible**  Please what are value objects then from the above requirement ?

Comment: Value objects are things that don't have identity, that's it. Think things like addresses, username, email address etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd split it slightly differently. You have a lot of the functionality in one BC when I think it naturally divides into two.

1. Sales
2. Stores (probably want a better word for this one)
3. Reporting

**Sales**

- Placing and validating orders
- Generating invoices
- Managing products (setting their prices, descriptions but not stock level)

Placing an order notifies Stores and Reporting of the order.

**Stores**

- Product inventory (products + stock level)
- Fulfilment? (i.e. shipping etc.)
- Generating low stock notifications

**Reporting**

- Managing reports

---

You asked about value objects in a comment - you do want to favour value objects when it makes sense. Remember that the difference between a value object and an entity is that an entity has identity (in the business context). E.g. customers/users, invoices.

Value objects don't have identity. E.g. email address, username.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'll definitely go for it. What about **User Management and Listing product on the web site catalogue ? Where do I place them ?**

Comment: Also how did you come up with such a decomposition? (sales, stores, reporting). Did you follow any principle or trick ?

Comment: User management will be its own context. I'd say the products listing belongs in sales - that's where you manage things like product descriptions and names. There's no trick, ask 10 developers and you'd probably get 11 answers. Try to model it as close to the real world as you can - ask domain experts, if they're available.

Comment: According to Eric Evans, he said to use Ubiquitous language to identify a bounded context... if we see the ubiquitous language change, it's a sign that you step into a new bounded context. but looking at this ecommerce system, the terminology PRODUCT for me has the same meaning in Stores, Sales, and Reporting BC. Can you anyone please explain that ?

Comment: You could put it all into one **if that's how the business treats it**. I was drawing on experience of working with a business where there was a hard divide between sales and stores. They both talked about "products" but they meant different things. One was a listing on the store front, another was a physical product on a shelf in a warehouse. The same word with different meanings

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification.